# UILabel text is not updating on iPad

Tags: ios, text, uilabel, updating, continuous

We have a delegate method which will be called for approximately 20 times in a second. In the delegate method we are updating our UILabel which represents the counter like below mentioned code:

```
    - (void) counterUpdated:(NSString *) value
    {
        lblCounter.text = [NSString stringWithString:value];

        // [[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]];

        // [lblCounter setNeedDisplay];

    }
```

I read similar problems in stack overflow and I implemented the solutions over there and I checked with keeping `[lblCounter setNeedDisplay];` method and `[[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:0.5]];` after updating `lblCounter`, but it is not working well as expected.

Any pointers?

Comment: You should log lblCounter to make sure it's not nil. Also, no need to use stringWithString: since you're passing in a string. The line should be: lblCounter.text = value;

Comment: Yep, `stringWithString:` is not required here, In the log, Im getting the `lblCounter.text` correctly, but the `lblCounter` is not updating on the screen.

Comment: What do you mean, that you're getting lblCounter.text correctly? It logs correctly, but you don't see it on screen?

Comment: Correct!! As of now I solved it by ensuring the label updation once in a second

Answer (score 0):

Try using Grand Central Dispatch in order to run this in the main thread:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    lblCounter.text = value; 
});
```

Comment: I tried to solve with GCD(dispatch_async), even though its not updating properly.